# getting embedded map code from database and using in input form as value

Tags: php, google-maps

I have stored following map code in mySQL database without changing something and when I retrieve this value from database and output it, correct map shows up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script><div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:600px;"><div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style><a class="google-map-code" href="http://www.mapsembed.com/voelkner/" id="get-map-data">http://www.mapsembed.com/voelkner/</a></div><script type="text/javascript"> function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:14,center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.8054567,-73.96547470000002),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.8054567, -73.96547470000002)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<b>The Breslin</b><br/>2880 Broadway<br/> New York" });google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
```

But when I use above code in value of input form then it doesn't work. I also have tried addslashes() but that didn't work.

Comment: *But when I use above code in value of input form* ...how do you use it there?

Comment: <input value="<?php echo $row['map']; ?>">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code contains characters(`< > "` ) that must be encoded when you use them in HTML-attributes:

```
<input value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['map']); ?>">
```

however, this will print the code as value of the input, nothing more.

Comment: It worked fine but just had to use another function.
htmlentities(str_replace('"','\'',$row['map']));